# Create a 'release' entry in Github

Tags: github

I'd like to create a `release` entry on my Github project.

I tried this from the cli

```
git commit -a -m 123
git tag -a "123" -m "msg"
git push
```

This commits the files but I don't see a `release` tab entry - nor do I see the tag.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, the git push command doesn’t transfer tags to remote servers. You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server after you have created them.

From [Git Basics - Tagging](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging)

- No need for the double quotes on `git tag` - `git tag -a 123 -m "msg"`
- Use the `--tags` flag on `push` - `git push --tags`

Comment: After I did the above 3 git commands - I haven't edited or done anything. can I do a `git push --tags` now? I assumed `git push` would push the commit files as well as the tags.

Comment: Yes, try it. By default, the `git push` command doesn’t transfer tags to remote servers. You will have to explicitly push tags to a shared server after you have created them.

Comment: do i do just `git push --tags` at the end to push files + tags or do I do `git push` and then `git push --tags`.

Comment: If you want to push your commits together with the tag you can use `git push --all`